# Motivation for considering cyclic and separating vectors

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, ho.history-overview

Is there a natural motivation which would lead someone to consider the notion of cyclic or separating vectors to study representations of $C^*$-algebras? It only arouses a vague feeling about approximations of vectors in me.  Did this idea originally come from the study of classical function spaces (like $L^2(\mathbb{R})$) and representation theory?

In a similar vein, what led Murray and von Neumann to consider the comparison theory of projections to study the structure theory of "rings of operators"? Were they trying to draw an analogy with some ideas studied before by other mathematicians in more classical circumstances?

In keeping with von Neumann's quote, "Young man, in mathematics you don't understand things. You just get used to them.", with time I have gotten used to these ideas and their successful applications. But it bothers me that I do not have a good explanation for a beginner to whom these ideas look exotic.

Thank you.